# How is "spade" and "shovel" racist?

Tags: word-usage, word-meaning, culture

In an [article at Quora](https://www.quora.com/What-are-some-great-examples-of-political-correctness-gone-mad) there's a mention that the terms *shovel* and *spade* might be interpreted as racist and cause someone to feel offended. I doubt not that there's always an idiot capable of feeling offended at any given subject but I'm still curious what the cultural connotation of those two particular terms might be.

> I was taught we can’t call it a shovel or spade. Might be racist somehow. So we had to call it an entrenching tool.

Comment: The "spade" (the playing-cards suit) is black. "black as the ace of spades".

Comment: @Lambie Well, apparently **someone** has said term can't be used for a tool (c.f. the article linked to). And I do agree that it's entirely stupid. One thing I find enraging is when someone takes offense **on someone else's behalf**. If a dark person asks me politely not to use the term *spade* because it bothers him, I'll probably oblige. But if it's a caucasian type, I'll most likely ignore him and probably speak my mind. Amazing to see if someone comes up with any explanation to the *shovel* part of the question.

Comment: @KonradViltersten I understand someone wrote that at that site. In a context re Afro-Americans, it is a racist slur. There is no doubt about it. What is wrong is about not using the term for a garden implement.

Comment: @KonradViltersten  given the quality of the other answers on that site, I wouldn't take anything they say seriously.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I don't have any idea why "shovel" is racist, but "spade" is a derogatory term for a black person.  The exact origin is uncertain, but possibly has to do with the color of the "spade" suit in a standard deck of playing cards:

[image]

As with many racial slurs, offensiveness depends on context.  Saying "Could you go find my spade in the tool shed?" is not likely to cause offense to anyone. It's only when you use it a deliberately racial context that it can be problematic.

[More information on the origin of "spade" as a racist term](https://www.npr.org/sections/codeswitch/2013/09/19/224183763/is-it-racist-to-call-a-spade-a-spade)

Comment: Very interesting article, +1.

Comment: It might be helpful to include an excerpt of the relevant section of the NPR article.

Comment: @V2Blast yes, probably, but the most relevant section contains numerous links to other source material, which would be difficult to copy over.

Comment: Well, you don't necessarily need to copy over the links, but it's helpful to quote the most relevant parts of the article that address the connection between race and the term "spade" so that the question is answered here, without people needing to read through the whole article themselves.